# Series approximation of exponential as argument grows large

Tags: taylor-expansion

Since $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$, it is known that we have uniform convergence of the partial sums $\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{x^k}{k!}$ to $e^x$ as $m\longrightarrow\infty$ over all the compacts $[-N,N]$ of $\mathbb{R}$. My question arises from considering $e^n$ and trying to see if as $n\longrightarrow\infty$, $E_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n^k}{k!}\sim e^n$. So I started investigating the error $\epsilon_n=e^n-E_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{n^k}{k!}$ and the question would boil down to show that $\frac{\epsilon_n}{e^n}\longrightarrow 0$ since $\frac{E_n}{e^n}=1-\frac{\epsilon_n}{e^n}$. However, using Lagrange remainder we know that for some $\nu_n\in(0,n)$, $\epsilon_n=e^{\nu_n}\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\sim\frac{e^{1+\nu_n}}{\sqrt{2\pi(n+1)}}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}=\frac{e^{1+\nu_n}}{\sqrt{2\pi(n+1)}}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\sim\frac{e^{\nu_n}}{\sqrt{2\pi(n+1)}}$ where Stirling approximation has been used and the standard limit $(1-1/n)^n\longrightarrow 1/e$. Hence, it all boils down to having an estimate of how slow $\nu_n$ is (the estimate above requires it essentially logarithmic, like $\log n^{\frac{1}{2}-p}$ for $0<p<1/2$). Unfortunately, I do not know of any estimates as to this. Are there any to the best of your knowledge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with common law Poisson(1). Set $S_n = X_1+\cdots+X_n$ for $n \ge 1$. The the law of $S_n$ is Poisson(n).

An application of the Central Limit Theorem yields that the random variable $n^{-1/2}(S_n-n)$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so its distribution function converges to the distribution function of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

As a result, $E_n/e^n = \mathbb{P}[S_n \le n] = \mathbb{P}[n^{-1/2}(S_n-n) \le 0] \to 1/2$ as $n \to +\infty$.

Comment: I believe there is a typo, you probably meant that $E_n/e^n=\mathbb{P}[S_n\leq n]$.

Comment: Indeed. I corrected it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very insightful answer, I was approaching it analytically and it did not hit me I could use a probabilistic approach, till I read 'Poisson' in your second line: than the connection sparked immediately. Thanks again.